# @Autowired inside SpringRunner SpringBootTest Unit Test Cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, autowired, spring-boot-test

Our Spring Boot REST API currently has a pretty large unit test repository. The unit tests refactor common reusable test code out into `TestUtil` classes which are `@Component` annotated.

It appears that the `SpringRunner` unit test cases can only find the `@Autowired TestUtil` classes if they are imported as part of the class parameter of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Additionally, all `@Autowired` variables inside the `TestUtil` classes also need to be imported in the classes parameter of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Since we have about 30 unit test case classes and each class needs to import roughly 40 other classes in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, one can imagine how unmaintainable this has become.

If a class is not imported as part of the `@SpringBootTest` classes parameter, the following error is thrown

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'com.company.FeeTest': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'accountTestUtils'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.company.accountTestUtils' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Does anybody know of a better way to use `@Autowired` annotation inside Unit Test Cases without having to explicitly import them inside the `@SpringBootTest` annotation?

A code example is below

FeeTest.java

```
package com.company;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        AccountTestUtils.class,
        ... need to list any @Autowired component in AccountTestUtils
})
public class FeeTest {
    @Autowired
    private AccountTestUtils accountTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void basicFeeTestExpectSuccess() {
       accountTestUtils.createAccount();
       ...
    }
}
```

TransferTest.java

```
package com.company;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        AccountTestUtils.class,
        ... need to list any @Autowired component in AccountTestUtils
})
public class TransferTest {
    @Autowired
    private AccountTestUtils accountTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void basicTransferTestExpectSuccess() {
       accountTestUtils.createAccount();
       ...
    }
}
```

AccountTestUtils.java

```
package com.company;

@Component
public class AccountTestUtils {
    @Autowired
    private IService1 someService1;

    @Autowired
    private IService2 someService2;

    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository1;

    public void createAccount() {
      someService1.doSomething();
      someService2.doSomething();
        someRepository2.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Our package structure is the common maven structure

```
/src
    /main
        /java
        /resources
    /test
        /java
        /resources
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: This error occurred when I switched from Eclipse + Maven based environment to Intelij + Gradle. My errors gone after restarting IDE and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Let me talk from the pov of TransferTest.java class.

This class tests the AccountUtilsTest class. So just supply the dependency of AccountUtilTest class to TransferTest.Mock each and every dependency which is auto-wired and used in AcccountUtilsTest.

eg:

```
package com.company;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TransferTest {

    @Mock
    IService1 someService1Mock;

    @Mock
    IService2 someService2Mock


    @InjectMocks
    private AccountTestUtils accountTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void basicTransferTestExpectSuccess() {
       accountTestUtils.createAccount();
       ...
    }
}
```